# Sum of first 1000 prime numbers

Tags: java

I have the below program where I am trying to find the sum of first 1000 prime numbers. In the code, what's the difference between solution 1, and 2? Why should I not put the count variable outside the if condition? I am obviously not getting the answer I need if I put the variable outside if, but I don't understand why its logically wrong. It could be a simple thing, but I am unable to figure it out. Experts, please help.

Solution 1:

```
public class SumOfPrimeNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long result = 0;
    int number = 2;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 1000) {
        if (checkPrime(number) == true) {
            result = result + number;
            count++;
        }
        number++;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of first 1000 prime numbers is " + result);
}

public static boolean checkPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Solution 2:

```
public class SumOfPrimeNumbers {    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long result = 0;
    int number = 2;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 1000) {
        if(checkPrime(number)==true)
        {
        result = result + number;                       
        }               
        count++; //The count variable here has been moved to outside the loop.
        number++;
    }       
    System.out.println("The sum of first 1000 prime numbers is "+ result);
}

public static boolean checkPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }       
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Consider renaming `count` to `primeCount` or `numberOfPrimesFound` or something like that. I think you've confused yourself through your naming.

Comment: Also, check this algorithm out for funsies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: By the by, sum of the first 1000 prime numbers is **3682913**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not check the return value of `bool` functions for equality to `true`: this line

```
if(checkPrime(number)==true)
```

is equivalent to

```
if(checkPrime(number))
```

Finally, the solution where the count is incremented outside of `if` counts non-primes together with primes, producing an obviously wrong result.

Here are a couple of points "for style" that you should consider:

- Checking candidate divisors in `checkPrime` can stop when the candidate divisor is greater than the square root of the number
- You can do much better if you store the primes that you've seen so far, and checking divisibility only by the numbers from the list of primes. When you are looking for the first 1000 primes this would hardly matter, but for larger numbers this could be significant.

Comment: result = result + number; (number is 2)

Comment: @user2341013 You're right, I thought your `isPrime` returns `false` for `2`, but it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think this is the efficient way of summing prime numbers, you will end up checking each number to confirm, the worst case scenario : the test case is a lot .

Answer (score 3):

The place where you increment `count` is pretty important. Your first code chunk adds up the first 1000 primes, while the second one adds up all the primes less than 1000.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution 2, `count` is incremented EVERY time through the loop, regardless of the result of your prime test. So it is not counting primes, but counting iterations through the loop. As a result, you'll check 1,000 consecutive numbers, not consecutive primes (which involves going through a lot more than 1,000 numbers to accumulate).

In addition to what others have pointed out, your check for prime can be made a little more efficient by:

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int number) {
    int s = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number));

    for (int i = 2; i <= s; i++) {
        if ((number % i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }       
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `Math.sqrt`. But it's pretty expensive - you probably only want to calculate that once. And your function returns `true` for `169` - you probably want `Math.round` and `<=`.

Comment: @Dukeling yes, all true. Thanks for catching that.